# transition not showing in chrome after page loads

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, transition

I have a div that hides until the page loads. Once the page loads the div shows with a transition.It works in Firefox but in chrome it just stops from showing.

This is the link so you can try in Firefox and Chrome and see the difference.

http://raulmv.com

The problem should be with the CSS but it seems to be a tricky one.

Thanks

Oh, yeah, I forgot to say that it works on my local using Chrome. That is quite odd I think.

**UPDATE**
*solution*

In the end for some reason I had to update the script this way

Instead of this:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('.slider').css('visibility', 'visible');
  $('.slider').css('opacity', '1');
  $('.slider').css('max-height', '4000px');
  $('.slider').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 2s linear');
  $('.slider').css('transition', 'all 2s linear');//notice this line
    },3000);
});
</script>
```

I had to use this:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('.slider').css('visibility', 'visible');
  $('.slider').css('opacity', '1');
  $('.slider').css('max-height', '4000px');
  $('.slider').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 2s ease-in-out');
  $('.slider').css('transition', 'opacity 2s ease-in-out, max-height 2s ease-in-out');//This is the line I changed
    },3000);
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure why but it works now on all browsers.

Comment: Works for me in both.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome 29.0.1547.76 at least... unless you have already fixed it of course.

Comment: it also works for me.. in latest chrome and latest firefox.. but in chrome the delay is slightly longer before it fades in

Comment: It still doesn't work on mine. I have version 30.0.1599.69 which it says it is up to date. I have disable all the extensions and still doesn't work. I feel comfortable to know it works for you but would like to know the reason it doesnt work on my machine at home neither at work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Transition to your Class before :hover and add this :

```
#clickme_about, #clickme_work, #clickme_interests, #clickme_find_me {

transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-property: color;

}
```

and delete the transition from your hover.

maybe it works without the short form.

(bouth works for me on chrome latest version)

Comment: hi thanks Alex, I don't think the problem is coming from those selectors. The transition is hooked to .slider not to those ones you indicate above. Still very strange it works for everyone but me.